# How do I securely login to a website within an iframe in an Asp.Net web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iframe, tableau-api

I am developing a web app which embeds an external website (Tableau) in an iframe. I'd like to know how to seamlessly login via the code behind **securely**? At the moment I'm simply posting the username and password by setting the parameters in the URL. Here is my code:

```
var getAuthUrl = WebServerUrl + "/auth.xml";
WebClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var authResponse = WebClient.UploadString(new Uri(getAuthUrl), "GET");
var authXml = new XmlDocument();
authXml.LoadXml(authResponse);
var modulusNode = authXml.SelectSingleNode("//modulus/text()");
var exponentNode = authXml.SelectSingleNode("//exponent/text()");
var authTokenNode = authXml.SelectSingleNode("//authenticity_token/text()");

if (modulusNode != null && exponentNode != null && authTokenNode != null)
{
    var authenticityToken = authTokenNode.Value;
    var postLoginUrl = WebServerUrl + "/auth/login";
    return postLoginUrl + "?" + "username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&authenticity_token=" + authenticityToken;
}
```

Code behind:

```
     tableauIframe.Attributes["src"] = postLoginUrl;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Logging in by query string parameters never is secure, as URLs get logged and cached.

Comment: Thanks CC. But that's why I'm asking, how do I login securely?

Comment: Your pretty much stuck. If it was on a shared domain (say you were mysite.com and the iframe was something.mysite.com) you could authenticate against the site and generate the auth cookie against the mysite.com (valid for all subdomains). For you, posting (i assume), to a third party site via Iframe less they have an API to provide you with, say, a session key to evade using auth over url your somewhat stuck. If there isn't an auth api or similar, you basically can't do what you want securely.